# Node JS + Express JS: refresh page from other location

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following problem: I want to change one variable on a page. The input comes from another page so:

I'm using Node.js, Express.js and Ejs for this task.

- Server - storing the values
- Index page - Control page with input fields and send button
- Display page - Shows the variable

I'm sending the variable with fetch post to the server. On the server I change the variable with the request body value and when I reload the "Display page" manually I see the new value. The problem is: I need to change it without any manual refresh or other things, because that won't be possible.

There is the possibility with "location.reload()" to refresh it every X second. But that's not the way I want to use, I really just want to refresh it when the variable changes. Is there a function (from express.js for example) I can use for it?

edit: I should mention that this project would be just used in our network and its not open for other users. Like an in-house company dashboard kind of.
So a "quick and dirty" solution can work too, but I want to learn something and wanted to do it the right way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common scenario that has several solutions:

1. **Polling** - The **display** page runs ajax calls in a loop every *N* seconds asking the server for the lastest version of the variable. This is simple to implement, is very common, and perfectly acceptable. However, it is a little outdated, and there are more modern and efficient methods. I suggest you try this first, and move on to others only as needed.
2. **WebSockets** - WebSockets maintain a connection between the client and server. This allows the server to send messages to the client application if/when needed. These are a little more complex to setup than just plain ajax calls, but if you have a lot of messages getting sent back and forth they are much more efficient.
3. **WebRTC** - This is taking it to another level, and is certainly overkill for your use case. WebRTC allows direct messaging between clients. It is more complicated to configure than WebSockets and is primarily intended for streaming audio or video between clients. It can however send simple text messages as well. Technically, if you want to persist the message on the server, then this is not suitable at all, but it's worth a mention to give a complete picture of what's available.

Comment: 1. Polling: I'm creating the page with the "render" function and with that I'm also sending the current value. So the ajax call would be the same and unnecessary?
2. WebSockets: That sounds good, I will take a look at that. Bascially the "Display page" is just a receiver for different values.
I hoped for a in-built Express.js solutiuon, where I just can say "refresh template/view x"

Comment: @Sega Polling: ajax call will be unnecessary but with a polling it's the only way to get whether update is required. To track the state you can do next thing: call ajax from a client for a first time. some value will be returned, as example 0, save it, don't refresh the page. When your variable is changed on server you should increase counter and return 1 from the server.  Meanwhile your client is requesting again, if it's still 0 do nothing if it's 1 than refresh. On a next load 1 will be stored as default state.

Comment: Once a request has completed Express has no knowledge of the client, so the notion of a refresh from Express' end doesn't work. Websockets bridge that gap, but may be overkill. If you really don't care about performance, then just refresh the page every N seconds - job done. But this will only work in a scenario where the page is _only_ for display purposes. If there is user interaction on the page, this would be a bad experience! If this is some sort of internal info page then I'd keep your boss happy and just add a one-liner to reload the page every N seconds - again, job done...

Comment: @Richard Dunn Thanks, yes that will be the plan for now. Maybe in the future the requirements will change but until then reloading N seconds will work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that came to mind is to have the server return the updated post in the body, then use that to update the page.

You can also read about long/short polling and Websockets.

Comment: This is good suggestion to use web sockets to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm rendering the page with the following code: res.render('/displaypage', { name1: name1, number: numer }); but I have to call that endpoint once to see the changes.
I will take a look at the Websockets though. I could just refresh it ever x seconds but in my mind that's too "dirty".

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to add page reload code after a successful post-operation with fetch.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: body
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {
        // refresh page here
        window.location.replace(url);
  });
```

Comment: If called on page load, and if the server returned 2xx, then this would result in the page reloading in an infinite loop - very inefficient, not to mention also rendering the page unusable.

Comment: You're on the right track though. Just don't reload the page. Update the local state instead.

Comment: I don't know if I mistaken but if I would do it that way, the page where I call to update the variable (let's call it "Control page" would change to the "Display page"?

Comment: @Sega - You're right. This answer is mixing up a few things. I'd steer clear.

Answer (score -1):

**Proper solution (WebSockets):**

1. Add WebSocket server as a part of your Node.JS app
2. Implement subscriptions for the WebSocket, implement function 'state changed'.
3. subscribe on a method 'state changed' from your client browser app.
4. call ws server from your express app to update the clients when your variable is changed

**Outdated (Polling):**

1. Add express endpoint route: 'variable-state' Call server from your
2. client every n ms and check whether variable state is changed.
3. Refresh the page if variable is changed.

Comment: Depending on the scale of your website the "proper" solution can turn bad and the "quick and bad" solution can save the day. For most of us websockets win every time. But if you are working at Google or Netflix scale you may find that persistent open sockets from millions (not hundreds) of clients will starve your OS of open file descriptors. At which point polling via ajax is a lot more scaleable

Comment: @slebetman cannot agree on your comment. You should not recommend something that is outdated just because there is a problem with one of the biggest websites in the world. Most of the users have another user cases and especially if they are asking this kind of questions here. Also there is a way to subscribe and unsubscribe with the WS, you can close the connection to WS, you can have few WS microservices to handle different pages.  So this is not a technology problem, this is technical problem.

Comment: I should mention that this project would be just used in our network and its not open for other users. Like an in-house company dashboard kind of. 
So a "quick and dirty" solution can work too, but I want to learn something and wanted to do it the right way though.

Comment: @IevgenNaida Ajax isn't outdated. The `fetch` API is even newer than websockets. Just because someone invented the electric drill does not mean the monkeywrench is useless. We are professional developers. We are not supposed to have fanboy-like mentality thinking something as stable and established as ajax is "outdated". As professionals we need to know our tools and use the right tool for the right job

Comment: @slebetman You are mixing concepts, nobody is saying that Ajax is outdated, but WebSockets updates are far more efficient than polling.

Comment: Like I was saying. You need to understand your tools. Websockets update are more efficient up to around 500 parallel sockets on Linux (up to 5000 if you configure your OS) and up to around 4000 parallel sockets on Win10 (or around 200 on earlier Windows). After that an ajax loop becomes more efficient than WebSockets

Comment: On Linux you can increase max file descriptors up to very large numbers beyond 100000 open connections (remember, these also share descriptors with stdin/stdout and open files on disk) but you may encounter unpredictable performance problems if the number of file descriptors is too high. Not sure if you can configure windows because the number appears to be defined in the source code

Comment: @slebetmen Thanks for the detailed answer, Quick googling is giving simple configuration examples for million or even two million of concurrent WebSocket connections. I would rather see how million clients will start DDOS a http server and what will be the difference between those opened ws connections https://medium.com/@alexhultman/millions-of-active-websockets-with-node-js-7dc575746a01